# Traversing a binary tree up to a given depth?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I have to traverse a binary tree up to a given depth and then determine the number of nodes after that depth but I'm having some trouble determining how to traverse up to a given depth. What I have so far is.

```
public static int sizeBelow (Node x, int y) {
    if (t == null) {
    return 0;

}else{

    int count = 0;
    int leftDepth = 0;
    int rightDepth = 0;

  if(leftDepth < y){
    leftDepth=1+sizeBelow(x.left, y);
  }else{
    count=1+sizeBelow(x.left,y);
  }

  if(rightDepth < y){
    rightDepth= 1+sizeBelow(x.right,y);
  }else{
    count=1+sizeBelow(x.right,y);
  }
  return count;
}
```

I'm probably doing something wrong with recursion, but my thinking was if the depth of the left or right isn't equal to the given depth, then increment depth and run again. If it is at the right depth then it should add 1 to the count and continue.

Comment: What you need is a DFS implementation where you should maintain a global variable for depth, and stop the recursion once the given depth is reached.

Comment: your question is a bit confusing, when you say depth 2 you should traverse `root` and it's child and stop there, right?

Comment: So say the given depth is 2, I what to get to depth 2 and then count the number of nodes after that depth if that makes sense.

Comment: @temptester1234 Yeah I got it and I added an answer. Let me know if you have any doubts in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we work out how to do this lets analyze the code below line by line...

```
public static int sizeBelow (Node x, int y) { // y is very ambiguous 
    if (t == null) {// I am guessing t should be x
    return 0;

}else{

    int count = 0; // the number of nodes below the depth barrier y
    int leftDepth = 0; // this will always be 0 since you never alter it
    int rightDepth = 0; // this to

  if(leftDepth < y){ // this will never not go off unless y is 0 
    leftDepth=1+sizeBelow(x.left, y); // we must decrement y
  }else{ // or we will never enter here 
    count=1+sizeBelow(x.left,y);  // this should be + =
  }

  if(rightDepth < y){ // this will also never not go off
    rightDepth= 1+sizeBelow(x.right,y); // y is again not decremented
  }else{ // this will never be reached
    count=1+sizeBelow(x.right,y); // this to
  }
  return count;
}
```

You have to understand that in recursion each function call uses new variables that happen to have the same name, the changes to right and left depth are never considered in the recursive calls unless you pass them in.

Here is my altered code

```
public static int sizeBelow (Node x, int depth) {  
    if (x == null) {
    return 0;

}else{
  int count = 0; 
  if(depth == 0){
    count +=sizeBelow(x.left, (depth - 1)); 
    count +=sizeBelow(x.right, (depth - 1)); 
  }else{  
    count +=1+sizeBelow(x.left,depth);  
    count +=1+sizeBelow(x.right,depth);
  }


  return count;
}
```

Comment: Sorry ya meant x on the first one. You say I never alter it but wouldn't it get altered when I call leftDepth=1+sizeBelow(x.left, y) since I'm adding 1?

Comment: read the final comment, that change is never saved in the follow up recursion calls.

Comment: This actually a very easy question, its kinda of like a standard binary tree count, but with an if statement.

Comment: Ah ok so I ended up calling count+sizeBelow(x, k-1) and just checking against K and and that worked. I think I was trying to get to complicated, but thanks for analyzing the code it really helps to be able to look at it line by line, which is probably how I should be looking at it in the future.

Comment: Give me best answer for helping

Answer (score 0):

You could search through the binary tree using Depth / Breadth first search. But make a few changes:

Create a variable outside the function:

```
int count = 0;
```

Add an extra boolean parameter to your recursive function:

```
public static int sizeBelow(Node x, boolean afterNode){
```

Once you hit the Node, use an if statement and set the boolean to true:

```
if(currentNode == x || afterNode){

    return sizeBelow(currentNode.right, true);

else{

    return sizeBelow(currentNode.right, false);
```

Apply the same method for the left child

Then add the condition:

```
if(afterNode){

    if(currentNode.right != null){
        count++;
    }

}
```

Apply the same method for left child again.

Do you see the approach?

You can use any binary tree searching algorithm

Comment: I see how this would work but this is for a class and I'm required to do it all within the function without changing the parameters.